# Updating relation in Hybris data using REST API, nested relation not saved

Tags: rest, api, sap-commerce-cloud

I've implemented tree structure and want to save items to database. Every item has "children" field with list of child nodes.

But if I send PUT request with something like this:
`https://localhost:9001/ws410/rest/pdsfamilies/8796093098749`

```
{
    "children": [
        {
             "pk": "8796093164285"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting response 200 OK but of course "children" list doesn't update. If I pull the item using GET again, it doesn't contain that change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try with relation type for pdsfamilies and children?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was weird nested object structure like this:

```
{
    "children": {
        "pdsFamily" : [
            {
                "pk": "8796093164285"
            }
        ]
}
```

I don't know why another property `pdsFamily` was needed. 
Also another weird thing is that in the response from GET I'm getting similar structure but the property is all lowercase `pdsfamily`... I have to create separate dtos for response and request just because of that...